# Blade: Undefined Variable Inside Foreach Loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

I have a controller which gets an array of a User's diaries from my database and passes them to my view:

```php
<?php

public function readDiaries($hash)
{
    $user = User::where('hash', $hash)->first();
    $diaries = Diary::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    return view('app.diary.readDiaries', ['diaries' => $diaries]);
}
```

In my view, I am looping through the diaries using a `@foreach` loop.

```php
<div id="diaries" class="card-columns">
    @if (count($diaries) > 0)
        @foreach ($diaries as $dairy)
            {{ var_dump($diary) }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

But I am getting the following undefined variable error...

> Undefined variable: diary (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\personal_projects\Active\diary_app\resources\views\app\diary\readDiaries.blade.php)

Why is my $diary variable undefined inside the `@foreach` loop?

Comment: just it is mistyping

Comment: just spell mistake in foreach `$dairy` and in vardump `$diary`

Comment: maybe just mark this as typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo

change `@foreach ($diaries as $dairy)` to `@foreach ($diaries as $diary)`

and it should work!

Comment: Sapnesh, thank you!! I am making another cup of (much stronger) coffee right away, far too early for this sort of thing!

Answer (score 2):

There is some typo in var_dump use {{ var_dump($dairy) }}
Try to use compact method for pass data to view as shown below

```
 //return view('app.diary.readDiaries', compact('diaries'));
public function readDiaries($hash)
{
    $user = User::where('hash', $hash)
        ->first();
    $diaries = Diary::where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->get();
    return view('app.diary.readDiaries', compact('diaries'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just a simple spelling mistake,

```
 @foreach ($diaries as $dairy)
  {{ var_dump($diary) }}
 @endforeach
```

in your foreach you are passing `$dairy` and dumping var name is `$diary`
chane it to

```
@foreach ($diaries as $dairy)
  {{ var_dump($dairy) }}
@endforeach
```

Habbit of copy paste is sometimes good for us...
:)

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach ($diaries as $dairy)
 {{ var_dump($diary) }}
@endforeach
```

you used ($diaries as $dairy) in foreach
but in foreach you used ($diary)

you want edit this {{ var_dump($diary) }} to {{ var_dump($dairy) }}
or you want edit @foreach ($diaries as $dairy) to @foreach ($diaries as $diary)